# Import Sharepoint excel files to MSACCESS

Tags: sharepoint-online

is there a way to import an excel file on a sharepoint to msaccess. I can import the sharepoint list but, cannot extract the actual excel file on that list.

Answer (score 0):

If the excel file is a list item attachment you will not be able to do this.  You can import the excel file as a new list then connect to that list with access.